# PHP + JQuery, how to use these two together in function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hi I am using this code for youtube video (Wordpress), how should look `$` php in this function if I need send my Https:/`

```
$(function(){  
    $('.Play').click(function() {
        $('.videoWrapper').show().find("iframe").attr("src","http://www.youtube.com/embed/'. $youtube_embded_code.'?modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&color=red&wmode=opaque&autoplay=1");         
    });
 });`
```

`$youtube_emded_code` - doesn't work inside "Http://"

---

Thank you so much for all questions but I still have the same problem(, problem is this is code works perfect without php `
 $(function(){
   $('.Play').click(function() {
       $('.videoWrapper').show().find("iframe").attr("src","https://www.youtube.com/embed/zyesmPtFziw?modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&color=white&wmode=opaque&autoplay=1");

});
 });
 `and .attr replace all "https://" to this part of php code :`$youtube_video=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'dt_youtube_video_url',true); 
             $youtube_embded_link = str_replace('watch?v=' , 'embed/', $youtube_video);
             $youtube_embded_code = str_replace('http://', '', $youtube_video);
             $youtube_embded_code = str_replace('www.youtube.com/', '', $youtube_embded_code);
             $youtube_embded_code = str_replace('embed/', '', $youtube_embded_code);
             $youtube_embded_code = str_replace('watch?v=', '', $youtube_embded_code);
                    echo '';
              echo '';
                    echo'';
                    ?> `

Comment: you should provide the full code before this as well.. you obviously can't mix use client script with server scripts.. so you have to process the value in your php first. `$youtube_emded_code`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question.

If the variable "$youtube_embded_code" is from PHP, you should just print it using the tags

Remember, PHP runs on server, generates the html and send to the client, Jquery runs on client.

So, your code will be like:

```
$('.videoWrapper').show().find("iframe").attr("src","http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $youtube_embded_code; ?>?modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&color=red&wmode=opaque&autoplay=1");
```

Answer (score 0):

What @Nauro da Silva Jr said, however, remember to make the php value global by `global $youtube_emded_code` if you are definin the php value in another document and need to send it between - or you can use `$_POST` or `$_SESSION` to save and send the php variable between documents.